# Sort by using Structure's arrays

Tags: c, sorting, structure

So I want to sort the list so that i can give them their position according to their grades but it's not working.

It is Showing error like : **incompatible types when assigning to type char from type struct info**.

p.s : I am trying to do this sorting using Structures.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3

struct info {
    char name[20];
    int number;
    double grade;
};
int main(void) {
    struct info list[SIZE];
    int i, j;
    char temp;
    int avg;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("Enter your name : ");
        scanf("%s", list[i].name);
        printf("Enter your number : ");
        scanf("%d", & list[i].number);
        printf("Enter your grade : ");
        scanf("%lf", & list[i].grade);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("Name : %s  Student Number : %d  Grade : %f", list[i].name,
            list[i].number, list[i].grade);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < SIZE; j++) {
            if (list[j].grade > list[i].grade) {
                temp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[i];
                list[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d st Position : Name : %s  Student Number : %d  Grade :  %f ",i, 
            list[i].name, list[i].number, list[i].grade);
        printf("\n");
    }
    avg = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        avg += list[i].grade;
    avg = avg / 3;
    printf("Average is %d", avg);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

errors are in the following code:

```
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {
    for(j=i+1;j<SIZE;j++) {
        if(list[j].grade>list[i].grade) {
            temp=list[j];
            list[j]=list[i];
            list[i]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: errors are in the following code !!! `for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
  {
      for(j=i+1;j<SIZE;j++)
    {
        if(list[j].grade>list[i].grade)
        {
            temp=list[j];
            list[j]=list[i];
            list[i]=temp;
        }
    }
  }`

Comment: Don't post the location as a comment, instead edit your question to add a comment in that location in the code you show. And copy-paste the *full* and *complete* output into the question body as well.

Comment: It works when I change `char temp;` to `struct info temp;`.

Comment: Thankyou Blaze :)

Comment: sure next time :) i am new here on stackflow so thats why @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @Muneer Then please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sure :) thanks for your guidence :)

Comment: can you not simply use [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) with a custom comparator ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker i dont know what **qsort** is :(

Comment: @Muneer : just click the link in my previous comment. It's a sort function provided as part of the standard C library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign a type `char` with name `temp` and try to assign a `struct` to it. Instead create a `struct temp` and then sort your array of structs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3

struct info { // use typedef struct info instead
    char name[20];
    int number;
    double grade;
};
int main(void) {
    struct info list[SIZE]; // allows you to write info list[size]
    int i, j; // do not initialize loop variables outside of their loops unless you need to(makes it easier to read the loop statements/spot mistakes)
    char temp; // you need to use a type info, not char e.g. info temp
```

I can not compile it myself at the moment, so please let us know in the comments if you have any further questions.